# Capitalize words in title page until hyphen

Tags: javascript, jquery, capitalize

This is the title of my page:

```
<title>john smith - Site and site - jobs</title>
```

I have to capitalize the title of the page until the first hifen (-). This is my code, but lost the second part and the first hyphen.

```
function toTitleCase(str){
    var str  = document.title;
    subTitle = str.split('-')[0];
    return str.substring(0,str.indexOf('-')).replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substring(1);
    });
}
document.title = toTitleCase(document.title);
```

Comment: Why passing the _str_ parameter to the function if you overwrite it in line 1 of your function anyway?

Comment: @roybatty What is correct output for you-> `JOHN SMITH`,or `John Smith`?  What do you mean by '`capitalize`'?

Comment: Capitalise ordinarily means the first letter, not all, which is the understanding I've based my answer on so I hope this is what he meant

Answer (score 1):

```
function toTitleCase(str){
    str = str.split('-');
    str[0]=str[0].replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
    return str.join("-");
    }
document.title = toTitleCase(document.title);
```

Comment: You will make `JOHN SMITH`,not `John Smith`

Comment: and his question was about the second part being lost

Comment: Don't forget to click on the check mark at the right side of answer

Answer (score 1):

Always good to throw in a nuclear REGEX route...

```
var str = "some words - are - here";
console.log("this is - a - string".replace(/^[^\-]*/, function($0) {
    return $0.replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function($0) { return $0.toUpperCase(); });
}));
```

Outputs:

```
"Some Words - are - here"
```

Comment: Nice. However `/^[^\-]*/g` seems to be enough for the 1st regexp.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I left the look-ahead in by mistake from a previous attempt. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing answers "best of" + my grain of salt :

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function () {
  return this.replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function ($0) { return $0.toUpperCase(); });
};

function capitalizeTitle()
{
  document.title = document.title.replace(/^[^\-]*/, function($0) {
    return $0.capitalize();
  });
}

capitalizeTitle();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you.

```
function toTitleCase(str) {
        subTitle = str.split('-')[0].capitalize();
        return subTitle + str.substring(subTitle.length);
    }

    String.prototype.capitalize = function () {
        return this.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) { return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase(); });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this please: http://jsfiddle.net/LK3Vd/

lemme know if I missed anything.

Hope this helps `:)`

**code**

```
var str = $('#foo').html();
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('-'));

str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help..

```
function ok()
{
  var str  = document.title;
  document.title=str.substring(0, str.indexOf('-')).toUpperCase()+str.substring(str.indexOf('-'),str.length);
```

}